# nativescript installation don't work everywhere

Tags: nativescript, android-sdk-2.3

i'm beginer in nativescript,i have correctly install **ANDROID_HOME environment variable** which return my **sdk path** after   `echo $ANDROID_HOME` but despite this it return me **The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set or it points to a non-existent directory. You will not be able to perform any build-related operations for Android**

but if i put my project in the same directory with **sdk directory** it return me
**Cannot resolve the specified connected device by the provided index or identifier. To list currently connected devices and verify that the specified index or identifier exists, run 'tns device'**

I also notice that after each computer restarting **environment variable** disappear and i must resume a same process , i have edit `.profile file, .bashrc file and zshrc file` for **environnement variable** i have a same result

please tell me what wrong ... thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my ~./bashrc file

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/user/Android/Sdk 
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/Android/Sdk/tools 
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/Android/Sdk/platform-tools 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64
```

In /home/user/Android/Sdk should be **tools** and **platform-tools** folders.

That's enough for me. (Linux Mint 18)

Maybe this information will be useful to someone:

**Linux environment variables configuration files**

**.bashrc**

This file is a variable for a particular user. It is loaded every time the user creates a terminal session, that is, in other words, opens a new terminal. All the environment variables created in this file take effect every time a new terminal session begins.

**.bash_profile**

These variables take effect every time the user connects remotely over SSH. If this file is missing the system will look for .bash_login or .profile.

**/etc/environment**

This file is for creating, editing and deleting any environment variables at the system level. The environment variables created in this file are available for the entire system, for each user and even for a remote connection.

**/etc/bash.bashrc**

System bashrc. This file is executed for each user, each time he creates a new terminal session. This only works for local users, when connected through the Internet, such variables will not be visible.

**/etc/profile**

System file profile. All variables from this file are accessible to any user on the system only if he entered remotely. But they will not be available when creating a local terminal session, that is, if you just open the terminal.

All the Linux environment variables created with these files can be deleted only by removing them from there. Only after each change, you need to either log out and log in, or execute this command:

```
$ source file_name
```

So, the environment variable can be of three types:

1. Local environment variables

These variables are defined only for the current session. They will be irretrievably erased after the session is completed, whether it is remote access or terminal emulator. They are not stored in any files, but are created and deleted using special commands.

2. Custom shell variables

These shell variables in Linux are defined for a specific user and are loaded each time it logs in using the local terminal, or it is remotely connected. Such variables are usually stored in configuration files: .bashrc, .bash_profile, .bash_login, .profile or in other files located in the user's directory.

3. System environment variables

These variables are available throughout the system, for all users. They are loaded when the system starts from the system configuration files: / etc / environment, / etc / profile, /etc/profile.d/ /etc/bash.bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nvm to manage different nodejs version, then try disabling nvm and using only one global nodejs version.

Regarding the environment variables that are being volatile, make sure that you track down the proper profile file that is being parse and place your changes there.

It would help if you can be more specific about your current platform. Then, people will be able to respond with more precision.

Comment: hi thanks, firsly i use gobale nodejs version, secondly this is `.bashrc` which is the goo file for me it's  him which return my **sdk path** thirsly i am on ubuntu 17.04 platform ,thanks in advance

Comment: does path to android in  `.bashrc` contains ~? as home folder? if yea you need full path to it @tnbsoftlab

Comment: this is this  path i export into **export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk** when i do it `echo $ANDROID_HOME ` return ** /home/tnbsoftlab/Android/Sdk**  
**I also notice that after each computer restarting environment variable disappear** and i must repeat the same process every time i don't know why ... thanks in advance

Comment: @MarekMaszay now i change my **sdk_path** by `export ANDROID_HOME=/home/tnbsoftlab/Android/Sdk` but i have a same result ...please can you give me an path example if the mine is false, also my project work only when it is in the same directory with **sdk directory** it's normal?

Answer (score 0):

hi i solve my problem by adding in `profile file` environnement variable

`export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk`

`export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk/tools`

`export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk/platforms-tools`

then i erased all path generate by all commands line entries from my terminal in `.bashrc file`(**i think that it was that the problem source**) . finally it work well thanks a lot to everybody for your helps